# RS485 connection

Tags: rs485

I have 6 TTL to RS-485 modules and I want to connect them in a way that disconnecting any specific wire from a slave module would only affect that one module, and the rest of the circuit should work fine. I have used arduino boards as slaves and one raspberry pi as the master.

My first question is, would such a thing even be possible?

If yes, then how should I connect these modules?

I have included an image showing what I have set up, but this current setup doesn't work as expected. For example when I disconnected the wire from GPIO PIN 8 of the first arduino board (and only the first one), it made the whole setup stop working. But then I changed the power source of some boards and the problem resolved. But now disconnecting two gpio pins from two boards would make everything stop working. I don't see any pattern about which boards or wires are essential to the whole setup. I guess this is a common ground problem. But to be honest I don't have enough knowledge about electrical engineering.

[image: my current setup; the raspberry on the top is only used as a power source, and the raspberry pi on the left is the master.]

The raspberry on the top is only used as a power source, and the raspberry pi on the left is the master.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome!  The main things when designing any RS485: what data rate do you want to use, and how long will the cables be?  (NB: it seems RS485 module 5 has its white cable in the grey bus.)

Comment: Would you please label your picture and indicate which modules are the TTL to 485 converters, which are the Arduino boards, which are the Rasp PI boards, etc?  And also which are the TTL signals and which are the RS-485 signal?

Comment: What is the function of GPIO pin 8 you talk about? Do any of the pins or connections have names we can know what they do? What modules those are, it may be important detail even if you think it is not. Do you supply them with 5V and are the IO pins 5V or 3.3V? If 5V you might have damaged 3.3V pins and the modules may not work at 3.3V supply. But you need to know these things before assuming if they can be just connected together or not.

Comment: "I guess this is a common ground problem." Do the two raspberry pis share a common ground? If they have separate power supplies have you connected their ground lines together?

Comment: @jonathanjo I want to use 115200pbs for data rate.
The A and B cables will be something like 100 meters but other cables will be very short (10cm maximum).
And that white cable going in the gray bus was just a mistake I made while making the image, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: The answer depends on the module. Of course in general it is possible to do a failsafe RS-485 system, but it depends on the module what happens if a single wire disconnects. If the module is badly designed, accidentally disconnecting the transmit enable pin may permanently enable the transmitter and it will be impossible for other devices to communicate. If you want a detailed answer then add the required details. Also please understand that RS-485 requires a common ground reference so two wires between each device is not enough, especially if they have separate floating power supplies.

Comment: "100 m" Are you planning to send power to the modules along the 100 m bus or provide local power to each module? How much power (or current) do the arduini and the RS-485 convertors need and, as Justme asked, is it 3.3 or 5 V power? Can your power supplies cope with the demand?

Comment: @Justme I edited the image and added a label for cables. the GPIO 8 pins are the pins on the arduino boards that are connected to RE and DE pins (to determine whether the module wants to send or receive data).
The modules that I'm using for ttl to 485 are MAX485.

Comment: You need to tie the grounds together between the slaves as well, not only A & B lines.

Comment: @Justme the module that I'm using for ttl to rs485 is MAX485. And I had also added a common ground between the MAX485 modules but it didn't solve my problem so I removed them. I think you are right about the transmitter being permanently enabled. what other details should I add?

Comment: @GrahamNye I'm gonna provide local power to each module.
And they all get 3.3V power. but I guess MAX485 works at both 5V and 3.3V

Comment: @mah We don't know which module it is and how it works if an IO pin is disconnected. Knowing which chip it uses is important but not enough. You need the schematics of the module.

Comment: @Justme I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by "which module" because as I said I'm using MAX485. are there different kinds of MAX485? here is a link to its schematics: https://www.openimpulse.com/blog/products-page/product-category/max485-rs-485-to-ttl-converter-module-3/

Comment: @MaciejSwic I have tried that but it didn't solve this specific problem.

Comment: @mah MAX485 is a chip. Different modules can use the same chip in different ways to make modules with different features and functions. The link you gave just gives me a security warning so I am unable to visit the schematics.

Comment: @Justme [try this](https://www.openimpulse.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/wpsc/downloadables/MAX485-Module-Schematic.pdf)

Comment: "I have tried that but it didn't solve this specific problem." You need a common ground throughout your system. You may well have other problems to solve but removing the common ground is just adding an extra problem.

Comment: "I guess MAX485 works at both 5V and 3.3V" It doesn't. It is a [5 V only](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/interface/transceivers/MAX485.html) device ([datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1487-MAX491.pdf)) and requires a 5 V supply. Your Raspberry Pi uses 3.3 V logic levels so to connect them together you'll need a logic level converter ([example](https://www.adafruit.com/product/757) - this one is bi-directional which is more than you need but links to other examples).

Comment: @GrahamNye Thank you for the information. But do you think it will cause a problem?
Because I've seen some examples of connecting max485 module to a raspberry pi and none of them have used a logic level converter.

Comment: "do you think it will cause a problem?" Multiple articles warn against doing this for fear of damaging your Raspberry Pi and suggest using logic level converters - [1](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2018/09/using-a-level-shifter-with-the-raspberry-pi-gpio/), [2](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=227262), [3](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=260730), [4](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/244496/help-understanding-3-3v-logic-vs-5v-logic-with-raspberry-pi-gpio).